# How to change branch cut of Log[z] to positive real axis,

Tags: complex

No one ever answered original ZZZ's question in a straightforward shortest code

" Mathematica chooses the branch cut for log(z) to lie along the negative real axis. It it possible to change this so that it lies along the positive axis or elsewhere in the complex plane?"

I don't understand the complicated answers given and the codes don't work. The natural cut should be a jump of imaginary part from -2pi to 0  when crossing the real x axis. Please give short understandable code and verify this

Comment: No that original never answered its question in its original simplest form. A general answer was attempted; I don't understand the code and Mathematica refused it to me

Comment: What is the simplest form? Why don't you post it as an answer? (I can't imagine a simpler form than one of the answers given there.)

Comment: I.e. if you want the branch cut at `θ = t0`, then `Log[-Exp[-I t0] z] - I Pi + I t0`.

Comment: So branch cut at θ = 0, then Log[-Exp[-I *0] z] - I Pi + I *0=Log[-z]-IPi.  Won't that jump from  -2Pi  to 0  crossing  +x axis

Comment: Yes, it does. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes it seems that is what was used in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756030/any-general-methods-to-calculate-integral-of-px-qx-from-0-to-infty/4608545#4608545

Comment: As I feared resolving this Log difference makes no difference to Mathematica saying it can't evaluate the residues for my rational function times the (amended) log . Not meromoprphic it says. Problem is in first place Mathematica doesn't integrate it from 0 to Infinity.∫0∞  dX (y+1+gtaX/ (g+tX)/ {(X-x)2+ (y+1+gtaX/(g+tX))2}/(1+ac/X)       or  XdX (1 + (g t a X)/(g + t X) + y))/((ac +   X) ((x - X)^2 + (1 + (gtaX)/(g + t X) + y)^2))